# What, if any, is the equivalent of bash's select...in...do..done in fish?

Tags: linux, bash, fish

I had finessed in bash a function that changes to any directory below the current working directory by having that directory name as a parameter to the function.  If there are multiple results by that name, a menu appears to allow the user to choose the intended destination.  The bash code is:

```
function cdb() {
  select dir in $(find -type d -name "$1" -not -path '*/\.*' -prune);
  do
    cd "${dir}" && break;
  done 
}
```

An example it of at play would be:

```
android@cybaryme:~/octos$ cdb av
1) ./frameworks/av
2) ./system/bt/bta/av
#? 1
android@cybaryme:~/octos/frameworks/av$
```

I use fish most of the time though, and would like to have this function there as well.  But for the life of me I cannot find the select command, or its equivalent.  Possibly thought that "complete" would do the job, but I got confused over what it is for.

Can anyone shed light on what is available?  Or maybe an example of a Perl script that can shim the missing gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fish does not have a `select` command. Nor can I find any indication that anyone has requested it be added. You can find an example of how to do the equivalent in a couple of the functions that ship with fish as well as my [mcd function](https://gist.github.com/krader1961/a4659e6bbe1649fc577331edc6936d9c) which will probably be added to the core package. Note that my implementation allows selecting by number or letter which is a pretty useful convenience. Feel free to open an [enhancement request](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new).

Comment: I've opened an issue to discuss implementing something like the base `select` command: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/4036